# Output color = background color, if run Grunt commands via ConEmu

Tags: conemu, far-manager

### 1. Summary

**If** I run Grunt commands in ConEmu, sometimes my output foreground = background.

**Else** I run any another CLI commands in ConEmu, I can't reproduce this bug.

---

### 2. Environment

- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN,
- ConEmu 180206 [64] Alpha,
- Far Manager 3.0 (build 5151) x64,
- Node.js 9.7.1,
- grunt-cli v1.2.0,
- grunt v1.0.2,
- grunt-hello-world 0.1.0.

---

### 3. Project

See example project configuration in [**branch SashaFarColors of my repository**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaGruntDebugging/tree/SashaFarColors).

For example, I use simply [**grunt-hello-world**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-hello-world) plugin, that print «Hello world!».

My `Gruntfile.coffee` file:

```node
module.exports = (grunt) ->

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hello-world')

    grunt.initConfig

        hello_world:
            world:
                name: "world!"
```

---

### 4. Steps to reproduce

1. I install [**latest portable ConEmu version**](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html),
2. I remove Far Manager → I remove all data from `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Far Manager` and `%APPDATA%/Far Manager` → I install Far Manager.
3. I print in $terminal:

   ```
   grunt hello_world
   ```

---

### 5. Expected behavior

**If** terminal == [**Hyper for Windows**](https://github.com/zeit/hyper) in Far mode:

[image: Hyper]

---

### 6. Actual behavior

**Else** terminal == ConEmu in Far mode:

[image: ConEmu]

Log (`Settings` → `Features` → I put a mark to `Log console output`):

```markdown
Far Manager, version 3.0 (build 5151) x64Not enough memory is available to complete this operation.Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to retry or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to continue…
D:\SashaDemoRepositories\SashaGruntDebugging>grunt hello_world
[4mRunning "hello_world:world" (hello_world) task[24m
Hello world!

[32mDone.[39m
```

---

### 7. Not helped

I try to change:

1. color scheme,
2. another different ConEmu settings.

Comment: To be sure, we need Ansi Log of the command.

Comment: @Maximus, `Settings` → `Features` → [**I put a mark to `Log console output`**](https://i.imgur.com/5IfMTOR.png). Is it «Ansi Log»? If yes, [**screenshot**](https://i.imgur.com/SULrgIm.png) and [**log**](https://www.pastery.net/hjywhd/). Thanks.

Comment: In the log I don't see bg/fg change requests. That meens some application (I don't know what exactly: Far/Node/Grunt) changes bg/fg via Window API. To go further I need sample repo to run grunt command and exact version of the Node.

Comment: @Maximus, I [**overwrite a question**](https://superuser.com/revisions/1198421/2). I add example simply repository and versions of my environment to new question revision. // Also, see section 5: if I run Far Manager via Hyper, I can't reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Maximus, **Status: Fixed for me** in ConEmu 180422 [64]. Please, add an answer, that I could raise your reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed in [build 180309](https://conemu.github.io/blog/2018/03/09/Build-180309.html).